# AWS CloudSearch - Não consigo buscar palavras que terminam com a string

Tags: amazon-aws, cloud-search

Estou usando o `CloudSearch` da `Amazon`. Porém estou com um problema ao procurar as palavras que terminam com determinado termo, não consigo realizar esse tipo de busca, ele me retorna apenas os registros que começam com o termo, por exemplo:
Tenho cadastrado `TESTEA` e `ATESTE`.

Digito: `TESTE*` ou `TESTE` ou `*TESTE`

o resultado será apenas referente ao `TESTEA`

Já li a documentação e alguns tópicos e não obtive sucesso.

Alguém já passou por esse problema e tem alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de algumas tentativas de exemplos e sem sucesso. eu resolvi da seguinte forma:

Criei um campo text-array e nele armazenei parte por parte da string de trás para frente e funcionou.

exemplo: minha string é "abcde" e eu procuro bcde. isso não funcionaria
mas no meu campo text-field estarão as seguintes strings: 
e,de,cde,bcde,abcde. Sendo assim  encontrará "abcde" pois vai encontrar o term no campo text-array.

Putz, mas e se eu procurar "bcd" este termino não está no campo text-array. Beleza mas a string "bcde" começa com  "bcd" sendo assim vai encontrar.

meu arquivo php para inserir ficou dessa maneira:

```
$term = "abcde";

$arrStr = str_split($term);
$arrTerms = [];
$aux = 1;
foreach($arrStr as $str){
    $arrTerms[] = substr($term,($aux * -1));
    $aux++;
}

$data = [
    'type'   => 'add',
    'id'     => [your_id],
    'fields' => [
        'id' => [your_id],
        'field-text' => $term
        'field-text-array' => $arrTerms

    ],
];
```